# Accessibility: adding visual labelling to a dropdown menu with a trigger button

Tags: html, user-interface, accessibility, wai-aria

I am building a user form that contains a date input field and a time dropdown picker.  It needs to be accessible and compliant with the WCAG.
I think it’s more intuitive for sighted users if we have a visual label to accompany the form controls.
In order for screen reader users to have access to the content in the visual labels, I need to explicitly link the labels to the form controls.

As the dropdown is not a search field dropdown, it just has a trigger button.

[image]

**CodeSandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-solomon-3nm8pe?file=/src/App.js:394-1066

**Desired behavior:**

Using a screen reader, the user will navigate to the start time dropdown menu, and the screen reader will announce: ‘menu button, submenu, start time, 12:00 PM’ or something along those lines. We want to get the visual label announced along with the current value of the dropdown.

[image]

**Problem:**

When the buttons contain textual content, screen readers such as NVDA do not expect any further labeling as it's usually not necessary. Adding further labeling, causes the screen reader announcements to not behave as expected. For example, the aria-label or aria-labelledby content is read and the content inside the button is not read. It doesn't seem like this kind of behavior is supported by screen readers for the button role.

Examples:

```
{/* works: start time, edit field, blank */}
<label id="form-label-4">Start date</label>
<input type="date" aria-labelledby="form-label-4"></input>

{/* does not work: start time, button */}
<label id="form-label-2">Start time</label>
<button aria-labelledby="form-label-2">12:00 PM</button>

{/* works, but not the desired effect: button, 13:00 PM. end time */}
<label id="form-label-3">End time</label>
<button aria-describedby="form-label-3">13:00 PM</button>

{/* does not work: button, start time */}
<button aria-label="Start time">13:00 PM</button>
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: You might want to follow the [W3C example for a dropdown listbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/listbox/listbox-collapsible.html)-- this looks relatively similar to what you are trying to accomplish, and they would be the authority on appropriate tagging.  If this example is not accurate to your use case, find one that is.  Looking at your codesandbox, it seems you are reusing the `"button"` `role` quite frequently at times that other roles might be more semantically appropriate... I'd suggest finding an existing example to work from from the W3C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to assign both a label and a value to a button component, but that's not what a button is designed to do - it's meant to have a label and potentially a state (e.g., for toggle buttons). You've created a button menu that behaves as a select-only combobox but isn't semantically a combobox.

In my view, you have two options:

1. Re-write the Start Time and End Time button menus as select-only comboboxes. You can refer to the [WAI-ARIA Practices example](https://wai-aria-practices.netlify.app/aria-practices/examples/combobox/combobox-select-only.html) to get a sense of how this component should behave with a screen reader.
2. You could add a second non-visible label to your button with the selected time and link it to the button using `aria-describedby`. This will announce the label, the role, and the value in the order you want:

```
<label id="form-label-2">Start time</label>  
<label id="form-label-3">12:00 PM<label>  
<button aria-labelledby="form-label-2" aria-describedby="form-label-3">12:00 PM</button>
```

Comment: Accessible **descriptions** (in this case, via `aria-describedby`) can be turned off by the screen reader user so the description might not be announced.  If you really want both labels announced, @george's option 2 is the best way to go but remove `aria-describedby` and put `form-label-3` in `aria-labelledby` so that you have **two** IDs in `aria-labelledby`.  You're allowed to have as many IDs as you want. `<button aria-labelledby="form-label-2 form-label-3">12:00 PM</button>`

Comment: That's a fair point. However I chose aria-describedby because of the order that the OP wanted the information announced, and if they add it to aria-labelledby it will be announced as label, value, role instead of label, role, value.

Comment: @slugolicious I have actually found that we have issues on mac with VoiceOver doing this: <button aria-labelledby="form-label-2 form-label-3">12:00 PM</button>

Comment: @user1261710 what kind of "issues"?  I use `aria-labelledby` with multiple IDs all the time with Voiceover.